# Make: "The system cannot find the path specified" only when compiling with makefile?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, gnu-make

I have a C-application that i'm trying to build with a makefile. When I call make I get:

```
Compiling file: nrf_drv_rtc.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu99 -Wall -O0 -g3 -mfloat-abi=soft -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -c -o build/nrf_drv_rtc.o nrf51_sdk/drivers_nrf/rtc/nrf_drv_rtc.c
"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.9 2015q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc" -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu99 -Wall -O0 -g3 -mfloat-abi=soft -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -c -o build/nrf_drv_rtc.o nrf51_sdk/drivers_nrf/rtc/nrf_drv_rtc.c
The system cannot find the path specified.
make[1]: *** [build/nrf_drv_rtc.o] Error 1
```

And true enough no "build/nrf_drv_rtc.o" file is build. Strange thing is that if i copy the line:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu99 -Wall -O0 -g3 -mfloat-abi=soft -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -c -o build/nrf_drv_rtc.o nrf51_sdk/drivers_nrf/rtc/nrf_drv_rtc.c
```

to cmd and runs it, it compiles fine and generate "build/nrf_drv_rtc.o"?

Here's my makefile:

```
PROJECT_NAME := ble_app_hrs_s110_pca10028

export OUTPUT_FILENAME
#MAKEFILE_NAME := $(CURDIR)/$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))
MAKEFILE_NAME := $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
MAKEFILE_DIR := $(dir $(MAKEFILE_NAME) ) 

TEMPLATE_PATH = nrf51_sdk/toolchain/gcc
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)/Makefile.windows
else
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)/Makefile.posix
endif

MK := mkdir
RM := rm -rf

#echo suspend
ifeq ("$(VERBOSE)","1")
NO_ECHO := 
else
NO_ECHO := @
endif

# Toolchain commands
CC              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc"
AS              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-as"
AR              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-ar" -r
LD              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-ld"
NM              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-nm"
OBJDUMP         := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-objdump"
OBJCOPY         := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-objcopy"
SIZE            := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-size"

#function for removing duplicates in a list
remduplicates = $(strip $(if $1,$(firstword $1) $(call remduplicates,$(filter-out $(firstword $1),$1))))

#source common to all targets
C_SOURCE_FILES += \
nrf51_sdk/drivers_nrf/rtc/nrf_drv_rtc.c \
Drivers/NRF51_BLEDriver.c \
(..... a lot more files ....)

#assembly files common to all targets
ASM_SOURCE_FILES  = nrf51_sdk/toolchain/gcc/gcc_startup_nrf51.s

#includes common to all targets
INC_PATHS  = -I Application/
(..... a lot more include paths.......)

OBJECT_DIRECTORY = _build
LISTING_DIRECTORY =$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)
OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY =$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)

# Sorting removes duplicates
BUILD_DIRECTORIES := $(sort $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY) $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY) $(LISTING_DIRECTORY) )

#flags common to all targets
CFLAGS  = -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
CFLAGS += -DNRF51
CFLAGS += -DS110
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10028
CFLAGS += -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu99
CFLAGS += -Wall -O0 -g3
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=soft
# keep every function in separate section. This will allow linker to dump unused functions
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing
#CFLAGS += -flto -fno-builtin

# keep every function in separate section. This will allow linker to dump unused functions
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -Map=$(LISTING_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).map
LDFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -L $(TEMPLATE_PATH) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
LDFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0
# let linker to dump unused sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
# use newlib in nano version
LDFLAGS += --specs=nano.specs -lc -lnosys

# Assembler flags
ASMFLAGS += -x assembler-with-cpp
ASMFLAGS += -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF51
ASMFLAGS += -DS110
ASMFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10028
ASMFLAGS += -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD
#default target - first one defined
#default: clean nrf51422_xxac_s110

#building all targets
all: #clean
    #$(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e cleanobj
    $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e nrf51422_xxac_s110 

#target for printing all targets
help:
    @echo following targets are available:
    @echo   nrf51422_xxac_s110
    @echo   flash_softdevice


C_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES = $(notdir $(C_SOURCE_FILES))
C_PATHS = $(call remduplicates, $(dir $(C_SOURCE_FILES) ) )
C_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(C_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES:.c=.o) )

ASM_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES = $(notdir $(ASM_SOURCE_FILES))
ASM_PATHS = $(call remduplicates, $(dir $(ASM_SOURCE_FILES) ))
ASM_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(ASM_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES:.s=.o) )

vpath %.c $(C_PATHS)
vpath %.s $(ASM_PATHS)

OBJECTS = $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)

nrf51422_xxac_s110: OUTPUT_FILENAME := nrf51422_xxac_s110
nrf51422_xxac_s110: LINKER_SCRIPT=ble_app_hrs_gcc_nrf51.ld
nrf51422_xxac_s110: $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking target: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e finalize

## Create build directories
$(BUILD_DIRECTORIES):
    echo $(MAKEFILE_NAME)
    $(MK) $@

# Create objects from C SRC files
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling file: $(notdir $<)
    @echo arm-none-eabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<

# Assemble files
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.s
    @echo Compiling file: $(notdir $<)
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<


# Link
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out: $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking target: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out


## Create binary .bin file from the .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin

## Create binary .hex file from the .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

finalize: genbin genhex echosize

genbin:
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin

## Create binary .hex file from the .out file
genhex: 
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

echosize:
    -@echo ""
    $(NO_ECHO)$(SIZE) $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    -@echo ""

clean:
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES)

cleanobj:
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES)/*.o

flash: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    @echo Flashing: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$<.hex
    nrfjprog --reset --program $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$<.hex)

## Flash softdevice
flash_softdevice: 
    @echo Flashing: s110_softdevice.hex
    nrfjprog --reset --program nrf51_sdk/softdevice/s110/hex/s110_softdevice.hex
```

Comment: What happens if you use the full path `"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.9 2015q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc"` ?

Comment: @NZD Then it doesn't work as well! And I just realized that I don't have "4.9 2015q1" .. I am using "4.9 2015q2" why would it think to use the q1 version?

Comment: So changing `GNU_INSTALL_ROOT` to `...q2` solved the issue?

Comment: @alk I have no such system variable? :(

Comment: This makefile again? Maybe it would be easier to create you own makefile, how is structured your project?

Comment: "*I have no such system variable*" You do have. Your makefile uses it. It must be defined somewhere. Look inside the files that get included from the makefile.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that skilled in makefiles - which files are you referring to @alk ?

Comment: Have a look at the `include` directives.

Comment: Ah! Got it.. It was defined in "nrf51_sdk/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.windows" fixed the issue! Thank you. Do you wanna throw an answer? :)

Comment: @alk it seems Jolle said something to you.

Comment: Just go for answering the question yourself. You as well can accept your own answer to own question. :-) From my side this was just a guess. You solved the real issue though.

Comment: @jdarthenay: Thanks for notifying, BTW. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, that the include: `include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)/Makefile.windows` defined the `GNU_INSTALL_ROOT` variable as a compiler version that wasn't installed on my computer. So I corrected it, and everything works like a charm .